# help with Remy Sharp's JQuery Marquee Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, json, twitter

I am trying to implement a solution so show the latest tweets for a certain hashtag.

I took inspiration from this `http://exscale.se/__files/uploads/scrolling-twitter-feed.htm` but it uses the actual user's timelines and not the search api.

Plugin demo page here: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

So far I have written this but the text remains stationary:

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=';
var query='%23MYHASHTAG';
var options='&result_type=recent&rpp=1&page=1&callback=?';

$(".results").append('<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">');

$.getJSON(url+query+options,function(json){     
    $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
        $(".results").append('<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" width="26" height="26" />'+tweet.from_user+': '+tweet.text+'</p>');
    });

$(".results").append('</marquee>');

});
});
$('div.results marquee').marquee();
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="results"></div>
```

I am at a loss as to why this isn't working - there are no errors on the firebug console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=';
var query='%23HASHTAG';
var options='&result_type=recent&rpp=1&page=1&callback=?';
var html='<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">';

$.getJSON(url+query+options,function(json){     
    $.each(json.results,function(i,tweet){
        html+='<p><img src="'+tweet.profile_image_url+'" width="26" height="26" />'+tweet.from_user+': '+tweet.text+'</p>';
    });

    html += '</marquee>';
    $(".results").append(html);
    $('div.results marquee').marquee();

    });
});
```